# Wordpress - Link attachments to post with raw php sql query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm working on a mobile version of a wordpress site (that will run on a subdomain and sharing the WP database), there is just a few static pages and 2 dynamic ones, one that lists WP posts and one with a form that allow users to post content with attachments. It's raw PHP so I'm not using WP functions; listing/creating new posts & creating attachment was easy but I have an issue linking attachments to the post...

When I post an attachment, I create an entry in wp_posts with an 'attachment' custom type and the parent ID set to the ID of the post I created before, then I create an entry in wp_postmeta with the attachement ID, the meta_key '_wp_attached_file' and the attachement path.

The problem is that the attachment doesn't seem to be linked with the post... Actually, it doesn't even show up in the media library. So I guess there is something more to do but I can't find out what, any idea ?

Comment: i think you need _wp_attachment_metadata meta key as well in postmeta table

Comment: I tried but it didn't work either... Also, I have other attachments generated with wp_insert_attachment() on the WP website without metadata and in works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem and as usual it was really stupid: instead of 'attachment' I wrote 'attachement' (note the extra 'e') for the 'post_type'... That's the problem of being french.